# How to parse JSON retrieved from URL?

Tags: jquery, json, jsp

I'm trying to retrieve and parse JSON in a JSP. The URL returns the following JSON string:

```
{"status":1,"msg":"List of Rooms","id":["1","2","3"],"name":["php","Java","myroom4"]}
```

I have attempted to parse it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $.get('url', function(data, textStatus) {
        alert('Status is '+textStatus);
        alert('JSON data string is: '+data);

        var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
        var myJson = JSON.parse(textStatus);
        var myJsonObj = jsonParse(myJson);

        var x=document.getElementById("Roomcount");
        alert(x.innerHTML);
    }, 'text');
</script>
```

I am not able to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the data type to `'text'` instead of `'json'`. This is not going to work. Fix or remove it. The `$.get()` will return `data` as JSON already if the `Content-Type` header is properly set on the server side. Assuming that the URL points to a servlet, you need to add this line before writing to the response:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

This way the `data` will directly be a JSON object already which you can access as follows:

```
$.get('url', function(data) {
    alert(data.status); // 1
    alert(data.msg); // List of rooms
    alert(data.id); // ["1","2","3"]
    alert(data.name); // ["php","Java","myroom4"]
});
```